Could not able to pause DAPR workflow
I am using this statement to pause the running dapr workflow using this code line;
await _daprClient.PauseWorkflowAsync("cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11023", "dapr");

I am following this help page.
This is the status of my workflow;
{
    "instanceID": "cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11023",
    "workflowName": "IFPParentWF",
    "createdAt": "2024-05-31T11:58:24.527681800Z",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2024-05-31T11:58:24.604734500Z",
    "runtimeStatus": "RUNNING",
    "properties": {
        "dapr.workflow.custom_status": "\"Waiting for InitiatedWF input from user.\"",
        "dapr.workflow.input": "\r\n        {\r\n            \"Application\": {\r\n                \"Name\": \"Sample Application\",\r\n                \"Address\": \"123 Main St\",\r\n                \"Zip\": \"90210\",\r\n                \"County\": \"Los Angeles\",\r\n                \"State\": \"CA\",\r\n                \"Phone\": 1234567890\r\n            },\r\n            \"Actions\": [\r\n                {\r\n                    \"TargetWorkflowName\": \"IFPParentWF\",\r\n                    \"ActionName\": \"Started\"\r\n                }\r\n            ]\r\n        }"
    }
}

I got the following inner exception.

Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error connecting to subchannel.", DebugException="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.")

